# Is there a way to use an if statement as an argument?

Tags: python, if-statement

Is it possible to use an if statement as an argument for another if statement ?

Like if one if statement is correct then the other if statement does this, but i'm not talking about nested ifs. Like if you have 3 if statements,

Is it possible to say if all those 3 are true then do this, or if all 3 of them are false then do this?

Comment: Looks like you're looking for `all()`.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's what a logical statement is for:

```
if condition1 and condition2 and condition3:
    # do something if all three are true
else:
    # not all three are true
```

If you have a variable number of elements to test, you could use [`all()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all):

```
if all(conditions):
```

or with a generator expression:

```
if all(val == testvale for val in sequence_of_values):
```

Any of these expressions can be stored in a variable first:

```
list_of_conditions = [condition1, condition2, condition3]

if some_fourth_condition and all(list_of_conditions):
```

but then you lose the short-circuiting behaviour of the `and` operand; all 3 condition expressions will be evaluated to build `list_of_conditions`, while `and` won't evaluate the right-hand expression if the left-hand expression resolved to a false value.

Last, but not least, there is the [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions), which returns the outcome of one of two expressions based on an boolean test:

```
outcome = true_expression if test_expression else false_expression
```

and only one of `true_expression` or `false_expression` will actually be evaluated based on the outcome of `test_expression`.

Comment: @user2840982: The test can be stored in a variable, yes.

Comment: What I mean is, could you make an if statement into a variable. For example, a = if(condition == True) b = if(condition == True) if(a == True and b == True)

Comment: @user2840982: Remove the `if`. `condition == True` **is** a boolean expression. `b = (condition == True) and (a == True and b == True)` can be simplified further to `b = condition and a and b`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean [`and`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/boolean.html):

```
if <condition1> and <condition2> and <condition3>:
    # All three conditions were True
elif not <condition1> and not <condition2> and not <condition3>:
    # All three conditions were False
```

Of course, you could also use [`all`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#all) and [`any`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#any):

```
if all((<condition1>, <condition2>, <condition3>)):
    # All three conditions were True
elif not any((<condition1>, <condition2>, <condition3>)):
    # All three conditions were False
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would be useful for you:

```
x = 1
y = 2
z = 3
my_function(x if x > z else y) # function called with y
x = 4
my_function(x if x > z else y) # function called with x
```

It can of course be combined with `all()` and `any()` as described by others.